# Mongoose Update Array inside Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model as below:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("557138249d46084df20620dd"),
    name: "Example"
    employee: [
        {
            username: "example@domain.com",
            address: [
                {
                    street: "123 Hill Ave"
                    country: US
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There can be many `employee` and each employee has an `array` of **address**. I would like to update all address of employee inside array as empty array. So, the result will be like -

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("557138249d46084df20620dd"),
    name: "Example"
    employee: [
        {
            username: "example@domain.com",
            address: []
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I query to update an address of all documents as empty array? Thanks.

Comment: you want also changed the key name like in your expected output you replaced `employee` to `companies` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got a solution and it is worked. Thanks.

```
db.example.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc.employee.forEach(function(em){
        em.address=[];
    })
    db.example.save(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it in a single mongoose method. It can be done with a simple loop and save though:

```
Model.findOne({query}, function(err, model) {
    if (err) {return callback(err);}

    for (var emp in model.employees) {
        model.employees[emp].address = [];
    }

    model.save(callback);
});
```